# why javascript window.print does not work correctly on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I preform a function to print content of a special div in document.

```
function printContent(el) {
var restorepage = $("body").html();
var printcontent = $("#" + el).clone();

$("body").empty().html(printcontent);
window.print();
$("body").html(restorepage);
}
```

my code run correctly on desktop, but on the phone; it print all the body content!
why does this happen?
thanks

Comment: what browser do you use on your phone?

Comment: First of all, what you do here will destroy all dynamic functionality in your page because all element references are invalidated and all event listeners removed. Secondly, the right way to print only part of the page is using CSS: Use a media query to set everything except for the stuff you want on `display: none;` if it's a `print` medium. You can also dynamically generate CSS for that if `el` isn't static (but depending on where in the DOM tree the element is located, you have to create rules for parent elements as well).